# Why does Mathematica give an incorrect answer to this multiple integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

This is not a new problem but I would like to understand why Mathematica gives the result that it does. (Volume of a hypersphere)

```
In[4]:= Integrate[
  Boole[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2 + x6^2 < r^2], {x1, -Infinity,
  Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x3, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {x4, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x5, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {x6, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {r > 0}]

Out[4]= -(1/6) \[Pi]^3 r^6
```

A negative answer is obviously incorrect.
Replace r^2 by 4

```
In[3]:= Integrate[
  Boole[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2 + x6^2 < 4], {x1, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x3, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {x4, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x5, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {x6, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {r > 0}]

Out[3]= (32 \[Pi]^3)/3
```

This is correct.

If we reduce the number of variables, then we obtain a correct answer:

```
In[5]:= Integrate[
  Boole[(x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 ) < r^2], {x1, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x3, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {x4, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {r > 0}]

Out[5]= (\[Pi]^2 r^4)/2
```

Comment: This is a known buggy area. If I recall correctly it undersimplifies assumptions somewhere inside due to either internal limitations or time constraints. You might get a better outcome if you first do this (it will influence that former issue): `SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"->{"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"->7}];`

Comment: At v8.04.0 it gives the correct result what's your version?

Comment: In 9.0.1 Mathematica also gives a negative answer and then fails to return any answer for the 8 dimensional cases. If memory serves, version 8 gave correct answers up through 6 dimensions and then failed on 7 dimensions. I note that the 9.0.1 answers would be correct if the sign was positive.

Comment: Daniel's suggestion is good but the problem remains.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, the multiple integrals can be generalized as

```
vol[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{x, var},
  var = Array[x, n];
  Assuming[
   {Element[var, Reals], r > 0},
   Integrate[
     Boole[var.var < r^2],
     Sequence @@
      Evaluate[
       {#, -Infinity, Infinity} & /@ var]] //
    Simplify]]

Timing[vol /@ Range[5]]

(* {96.016268, {2*r, Pi*r^2, (4*Pi*r^3)/3, (Pi^2*r^4)/2, (8*Pi^2*r^5)/15}} *)
```

The timing is somewhat improved by changing the limits
of integration from $\{-\infty ,\infty \}$ to $\{-r, r\}$

```
vol[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{x, var},
  var = Array[x, n];
  Assuming[
   {Element[var, Reals], r > 0},
   Integrate[
     Boole[var.var < r^2],
     Sequence @@
      Evaluate[
       {#, -r, r} & /@ var]] //
    Simplify]]

Timing[vol /@ Range[5]]

(* {64.282676, {2*r, Pi*r^2, (4*Pi*r^3)/3, (Pi^2*r^4)/2, (8*Pi^2*r^5)/15}} *)
```

Bob Hanlon