# Negative probability?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, probability-or-statistics, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

I am trying to get the sum of the squares of seven random variables, all  uniformly distributed. This is what I tried.

```
Probability[
  a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + g^2 < 1,
  {a, b, c, d, e, f, g} \[Distributed] 
  UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]
```

The output was

> ```
> -π^3/840
> ```

How can I get *Mathematica* to get the right answer?

**Warning:** the code takes about seven minutes to run on my machine.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  Version 8.0.4 returns `Pi^3/840`, which is [correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersphere#Volume_and_surface_area).  Version 9.0.1 has been working for much longer than 8.0.4 and finally returned `-Pi^3/840`, which looks to be a bug (possibly in the symbolic intergration code).

Comment: Just for fun: "Negative energies and probabilities should not be considered as nonsense. They are well-defined concepts mathematically, like a negative of money." - Paul Dirac

Comment: That's weird: I'm using MMA 9.0.1, Windows, 64bit, and I get `\[Pi]^3/840`.

Comment: @ Szabolcs I am using 9.01 on an XP machine.

Comment: @nikie I ran this on OS X.  `Integrate[Boole[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + g^2 < 1], {a, -1,  1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}, {d, -1, 1}, {e, -1, 1}, {f, -1, 1}, {g, -1, 1}]` also gives a wrong result: it has an extra minus sign.  (Somehow I though that extending the integration domain would help...)

Comment: I get - in the same environment as nikie - also \[Pi]^3/840.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Linux too (9.0.1 64 bit).

Comment: 9.0.1.0 on Windows (64-bit) reproduces the issue. Weirdly the platform and version seem to be the same as @nikie.

Comment: I confirm the problem also exists with V9.0.1 on OS X

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Mathematica give an incorrect answer to this multiple integral?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/why-does-mathematica-give-an-incorrect-answer-to-this-multiple-integral)

Comment: Have you reported this to support@wolfram.com?

Comment: I verified that the error first appears in the seven-variable case: `n = 7; as = Array[a, n]; Probability[Total[as^2] < 1, as \[Distributed] UniformDistribution@Table[{0, 1}, {n}]]` Strangely, Michael E2's linked question shows a similar problem with only six variables.

Comment: @Szabolcs et al: a bit of a stretch at this time but do you know if this is present in 9.0.0?  I marked it as introduced in 9.0.1 but that may be incorrect.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, I can't test as I don't keep old point versions (only the latest of each major version)

Comment: I think it is related to the fact that -3 out of every 5 people really don't grasp probability..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not an answer (yet). Rather it explores the question in more depth.

```
n = 8;
parameters = ConstantArray[{0, 1}, n];
variables = 
  Symbol /@ CharacterRange["a", FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode["a"] + n - 1]];
```

The following takes a long time to evaluate, but the results it produces reveal give us a better view of the problem with `Probability`.

```
Table[
  With[{params = parameters[[;; i]], vars = variables[[;; i]]}, 
    Probability[vars.vars < 1, vars \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[params]]], 
  {i, n}]
```

> ```
> {1, π/4, π/6, π^2/32, π^2/60, π^3/384, -(π^3/840), π^4/6144}
> ```

Only in the penultimate case is the result incorrect (its magnitude is correct but its sign is bogus). Why is 7 a (black) magical number?

I am going to send a query about this to WRI tech support. I will update this post, quoting their response, after I receive it.

#### Update

I have received an answer to the query I sent to WRI tech support. I quote the relevant part:

> The function `Probability` does behave inappropriately in *Mathematica* 9 on Mac for `i = 7` in the given notebook. However, this issue has been fixed and the performance is also improved in the prerelease version of *Mathematica*. Thank you for bringing it to our attention.

It seems that WRI was already aware of the problem and has fixed it in *Mathematica* 10.

Answer (score 3):

This is also not an answer but a brief study in

```
$Version

"8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)"
```

which might be of interest. It considers three methods of calculating the requested probability.

It shows that in this version there is no negative probability but there is still a "critical number" which amounts to 8. For n = 8 the calculation for two methods is not completely performed but the result is returned in the form of commands still to be done.

**Method 1**

use Probability[] as in the original formulation of the problem

```
p[n_] := Probability[Sum[a[i]^2, {i, 1, n}] < 1, 
  Table[a[i], {i, 1, n}] \[Distributed] 
   UniformDistribution[Array[{0, 1} &, n]]]
```

Calculate some values and measure time required

```
{#, Timing[p[#]] // Reverse} & /@ Range[8]

{{1, {1, 0.016}}, {2, {\[Pi]/4, 0.14}}, {3, {\[Pi]/6, 0.265}}, {4, {\[Pi]^2/
   32, 1.155}}, {5, {\[Pi]^2/60, 4.789}}, {6, {\[Pi]^3/384, 15.007}}, 
   {7, {\[Pi]^3/840, 34.336}}, {8, {Probability[
    a[1]^2 + a[2]^2 + a[3]^2 + a[4]^2 + a[5]^2 + a[6]^2 + a[7]^2 + a[8]^2 < 
     1, {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]} \[Distributed] 
     UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 
        1}, {0, 1}}]], 836.774}}}
```

**Method 2**

use Integrate with Boole

Notice that f(n) = 2^n p(n)

```
f[n_] := Integrate[Boole[Sum[a[i]^2, {i, 1, n}] < 1], Sequence @@ Table[{a[i], -1, 1}, {i, 1, n}]]
```

Calculate some values and measure time required

```
{#, Timing[f[#]] // Reverse} & /@ Range[8]

{{1, {2, 0.015}}, {2, {\[Pi], 0.203}}, {3, {(4 \[Pi])/3, 
   0.328}}, {4, {\[Pi]^2/2, 1.716}}, {5, {(8 \[Pi]^2)/15, 
   8.018}}, {6, {\[Pi]^3/6, 32.682}}, {7, {(16 \[Pi]^3)/105, 
   145.877}}, {8, {(-(4/3))*Pi*Integrate[
       Sqrt[-(1/Sqrt[1 - a[1]^2 - a[2]^2 - a[3]^2 - a[4]^2 - a[5]^2])]*
         (-Sqrt[1 - a[1]^2 - a[2]^2 - a[3]^2 - a[4]^2 - a[5]^2])^(3/2)*
         (1 - a[1]^2 - a[2]^2 - a[3]^2 - a[4]^2 - a[5]^2), {a[1], -1, 1}, 
       {a[2], -Sqrt[1 - a[1]^2], Sqrt[1 - a[1]^2]}, 
       {a[3], -Sqrt[1 - a[1]^2 - a[2]^2], Sqrt[1 - a[1]^2 - a[2]^2]}, 
       {a[4], -Sqrt[1 - a[1]^2 - a[2]^2 - a[3]^2], 
         Sqrt[1 - a[1]^2 - a[2]^2 - a[3]^2]}, 
       {a[5], -Sqrt[1 - a[1]^2 - a[2]^2 - a[3]^2 - a[4]^2], 
         Sqrt[1 - a[1]^2 - a[2]^2 - a[3]^2 - a[4]^2]}], 2290.718}}}
```

**Method 3**

volume of n-dimensional unit sphere

Exact values up to n=10 are swiftly calculated by this method for reference. Using polar ccordinates (see e.g. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarkoordinaten#n-dimensionale_Polarkoordinaten) we have for the volume

```
v[n_] := Integrate[
  r^(n - 1) Product[Sin[u[j]]^j, {j, 1, n - 2}], {r, 0, 1}, {phi, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
   Sequence @@ Table[{u[j], 0, \[Pi]}, {j, 1, n - 2}]]
```

Notice that v(n) = 2^n p(n).

Calculate some values and measure time required

```
{#, Timing[v[#]] // Reverse} & /@ Range[10]

{{1, {2 \[Pi], 0.}}, {2, {\[Pi], 0.}}, {3, {(4 \[Pi])/3, 
   0.063}}, {4, {\[Pi]^2/2, 0.14}}, {5, {(8 \[Pi]^2)/15, 
   0.234}}, {6, {\[Pi]^3/6, 0.375}}, {7, {(16 \[Pi]^3)/105, 
   0.483}}, {8, {\[Pi]^4/24, 0.702}}, {9, {(32 \[Pi]^4)/945, 
   2.621}}, {10, {\[Pi]^5/120, 4.103}}}
```

I have checked that there were no memory shortages on my PC. Hence there must be an intrisic reason in MMA for magic number 8.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 3):

Fixed in 10.0.2

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Probability[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + g^2 < 1, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g} 
  \[Distributed]  UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, 
    {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to calculate volume of hypersphere and then relevant probability using recursion:

```
vs[n_] := 
 Most@Nest[{#[[2]]/(#[[3]] + 1), 2 Pi #[[1]], #[[3]] + 1} &, {1, 2, 
    0}, n]
v[n_] := vs[n][[1]]
```

The probabilities:

```
Grid[Prepend[{#1, #2, N@#2} & @@@ ({#, v[#]/2^#} & /@ Range[10]), 
  Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"n", 
    "P[\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \
\(n\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(j\)], \(2\)]\)<1|x\
\[Distributed]Unif(0,1\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(n\)]\)]", ""}]]
```

[image]